# Executing an .exe file on files in another folder

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, pathname

I have my python code that runs a C++ code, which takes files in another folder as input. 
I have my codes in folder A, and the input files are in folder B, and I have been trying this:

```
path = 'C:/pathToInputFiles'
dirs = os.listdir(path)

for path in dirs:
    proc = subprocess.Popen([fullPathtoCppCode, inputFiles])
```

However, I keep receiving `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

The only way it works is when I put the C++ executable file in the same folder of the input files, which I am avoiding to do.

How can I make python reads the file path properly?

Comment: If you do ``import os`` and then ``os.path.exists(fullPathtoCppCode)``, what do you get?

Comment: @alexblae I tried it and got nothing! 
what am I supposed to get if everything was working fine?

Comment: You should normally get ``True`` if the file exists and otherwise ``False``. So it seems that the way you specified to path to the file, it did not really exist. But I guess the answer by @NineTail fixed the problem.

Comment: @alexblae Actually not. I just removed my comment there. That way didn't solve the problem neither.

Comment: Ok, well, then let's look. So ``print os.path.exists(fullPathtoCppCode)`` does not return either ``True`` or ``False``? Also, how does ``path`` in your ``for`` loop then gets passed to ``Popen``? Is ``inputFiles=path`` ?

Comment: have you tried using a \ instead of / ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using os.path.join after your for statement.

path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

for example

```
def test(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        proc = subprocess.Popen([fullPathtoCppcode, inputFiles])
```